# @nestjs/mongoose create connection every request

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I create connection by forRootAsync like bellow

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory() {
        return {
          uri: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDb`,
        }
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Test.name, schema: TestSchema }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and AppService

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection() private connection: any,
    @InjectModel(Test.name) private testModel: Model<Test>
  ) { }

  getHello(): string {
    this.testModel.create({ name: 'string1' })

    console.log(this.connection.base.connections.length); // the  number of connection increase by each request
    

    return 'Hello World!'
  }
}
```

At the console.log I saw the number of connection increase each request, is it okay?